# java - how to replace all substrings starting and ending with a particular character?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

> "The brown fox @jumped@ over the @fence@"

, and I wish to replace all substrings between two `'@'` by '`kicked`' i.e. the final output should be :

> "The brown fox kicked over the kicked"

I wrote the following but can't figure out the mistake :

```
string.replaceAll("^@.*@$", "kicked");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not use anchor elements `^` and `$`. They mean the beginning and the end of the entire input, not the beginning and the ending of the word. You should also replace the dot `.` with `[^@]` (meaning "anything but `@`") to make your expression more efficient.

```
string.replaceAll("@[^@]*@", "kicked");
```

If you would like to avoid replacing tagged elements inside a word, e.g. if you want to preserve `he@ll@o` as is, rather than making it `hekikkedo`, you can put in markers of word boundaries `\b` on both ends of the expression:

```
string.replaceAll("\\b@[^@]*@\\b", "kicked");
```